# Emacs: Is it possible to set specific indentation settings for specific desktops in desktop+?

Tags: emacs

I have to work on a lot of different projects that all tend to use different indentation amounts (usually just 2 and 4 spaces) for js, php, etc. I manage project sessions using emacs-desktop.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing this via emacs-desktop, I suggest using [Per-directory Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).  These are designed for exactly this purpose.

For example, here is the `.dir-locals.el` that I use for hacking on firefox:

```
(
 ;; Generic settings.
 (nil .
      ;; See C-h f bug-reference-prog-mode, e.g, for using this.
      ((bug-reference-url-format . "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=%s")
       (bug-reference-bug-regexp . "\\([Bb]ug ?#?\\|[Pp]atch ?#\\|RFE ?#\\|PR [a-z-+]+/\\)\\([0-9]+\\(?:#[0-9]+\\)?\\)")))

 ;; The built-in javascript mode.
 (js-mode .
     ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
      (js-indent-level . 2)))

 (c++-mode .
       ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
        (c-basic-offset . 2)))

 (idl-mode .
       ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
        (c-basic-offset . 2)))

)
```

This customizes the indentation for a few programming modes, disables `indent-tabs-mode` where it matters, and arranges to buttonize bug references in the firefox source.